# Spring Boot cache names and keys

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I'm trying to preload some cached functions for lookup purposes and I don't understand how cacheNames and key work here.
Can I have a cache keyed by different attributes and how do I tell the cacheManager put() function what key to use?

This is my UnitService (simplified for clarity):

```java
@Service
public class UnitService {

    @Autowired
    CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Autowired
    UnitRepository unitRepository;

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "unit", key = "#id")
    public Unit getUnitById(Integer id) {
        return unitRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "unit", key = "#serialNumber")
    public Unit getUnitBySerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        return unitRepository.findBySerialNumber(serialNumber).orElse(null);
    }

    public List<Unit> getAllUnits() {
        return unitRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void preloadCache() {
        for (Unit unit: getAllUnits()) {
            //Is this the right way to do this?
            cacheManager.getCache("unit").put(unit.getId(), unit);
            cacheManager.getCache("unit").put(unit.getSerialNumber(), unit);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example the serial number is 99% of the time a combination of letters and numbers but there are some erroneous data where it's just a number and this causes the findBySerialNumber function to return the wrong unit.

Would I be better of just having different cacheNames for the two get functions or is there some way to manually populate one cache keyed by two different attributes?